# Fastest method to display a 800 x 600 png rotating fast is?

Tags: c++, c++11, sdl-2

I want the 800x600 png to rotate twice or 3 times per second. Also, could I use a smaller png to increase performance without loosing visual quality?

With C++, SDL2 these are perhaps some methods to do this:

1.Huge 5mb png sprite sheet of the image rotating. Put that into SDL2 and display all the clips in a loop.

2.Get the png into SDL as a texture and use a method/function to rotate it. I haven't seen a clear example of this done...

Comment: Have you seen this one: http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/15_rotation_and_flipping/index.php?

Comment: Nice didn't know SDL_RenderCopyEx could take an angle double. Is it fast though?

Comment: Probably not as fast as OpenGL doing the rotation in a vector shader, but I don't know how SDL works.

Comment: OpenGL would be faster for sure but SDL would be quicker/easier to implement with `SDL_RenderCopyEx`. Depends what route you are going down. OpenGL has much more capabilities and would scale better but again depends if you need that as it may be the case that SDLs native rendering is suitable. You could use a smaller png but you would lose quality as it scales up and the performance gain wouldn't be worth it.

Comment: Thanks for answers. I Think SDL_RenderCopyEx should be good enough for what i'm doing now.